# Hiding an element with CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Using [CSS Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) how can I safely hide a row without `grid-template-rows` layout properties getting passed over to the next row? I tried `display: none;` but the layout of the hidden element is passed over to the next element.

Here's a code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/E3kuJcDxKnrjjbdVHQbO?p=preview. What I'm trying to do is toggle the visibility of the `.item2` element without effecting any other elements on the page. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @SauravRastogi added code. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: I don't want to take the answer from @SauravRastogi but he's right.

Comment: @SauravRastogi @NilesTanner `visibility: hidden;` isn't what I'm looking for, since the element is still there, just that it's hidden. It leaves an empty space. I don't want that space.

Comment: @shmuli Can you show me by an image, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.  You're setting the height of the second "row" in the CSS. Whether there is an element there or not isn't really relevant, hidden or not.

Comment: I am surprised this is not a more popular question. I'll go with visibility: hidden until I find something better.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by setting that row's height to 0 via the `grid-template-rows` declaration, and then setting the `visibility` of the element you want to hide to `hidden`.

Assuming you want to hide the second row:

```
.grid-hiderows {
    grid-template-rows: auto 0px;
}
.grid-hiderows .item:nth-child(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Similarly, to hide the third row:

```
.grid-hiderows {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 0px;
}
.grid-hiderows .item:nth-child(3) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you need your grid to utilize a gap between columns / rows, you won't be able to use the `gap` property when using this method. You'd instead need to resort to some negative `margin` manipulation to handle the extra gap space.

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item-fullwidth">1</div>
  <div class="item item-fullwidth" data-hideme>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/5eba7d/FFFFFF?text=Row+2" style="width: 100%;height: auto;display:block;"></div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
<button data-toggle style="margin-top:1em">Toggle hidden row</button>
<style>
:root {
  --gap: .5em;
  --rowHeight: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: var(--rowHeight); /* Or use grid-template-rows if row heights will need to be varied / manually set */
}
.item {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
  padding: .5em;
}
.item-fullwidth {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
[data-hideme] {
  padding: 0;
}

/**
  *
  * Define toggled state
  * @ change the appropriate row's height on the parent grid to 0 via `grid-template-rows`
  * @ change the element to hide's visibility to 'hidden'
  *
**/
.grid-hiderows {
  grid-template-rows: var(--rowHeight) 0;
}
.grid-hiderows [data-hideme] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/**
  *
  * Allow for gaps between rows / columns
  *
**/
.grid {
  margin-left: calc(var(--gap)/-2);
  margin-right: calc(var(--gap)/-2);
}
.item {
  margin-right: calc(var(--gap)/2);
  margin-left: calc(var(--gap)/2);
}
.item + .item {
  margin-top: var(--gap);  
}
</style>
<script>
document.querySelector('[data-toggle]').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.grid').classList.toggle("grid-hiderows");
};
</script>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.  Any contents in .`item2` are treated as if they are not inside the hidden grid, and now take up space in the grid flow.  Have to use `display:none` not visibility hidden.

Comment: @JamieMarshall I made some updates to allow the row count to be less rigid. Lemme know if that resolved the issue you're seeing?

Answer (score -1):

Set the row height for each individual item instead grid-template-rows. Then 'display: none' will work.

Comment: This does not prevent layout properties being passed to the next available cell in the grid.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: This would be the answer if it were possible but it is not possible to set "row-hight" .